# Query to group rows together then sort in those groups

Tags: sql, sorting

The question might sound a little weird. I have a `Pages` table as follows:

```
Id    PageName    Parent    Predecessor  
1     Home        null      null  
2     About       null      1  
3     Contact me  2         null  
4     My Resume   2         3
```

So it is basically like:

```
Home  
About  
|--Contact me  
|--My resume
```

I want to write a select query that will first "group" pages based on their `Parent` then sort in those groups based on the value of their `Predecessor`. That is preserve the tree structure of those pages. Needless to say, `Parent` and `Predecessor` are foreign keys pointing to `Id` in the same `Pages` table.
Any help is greatly appreciated :-) Thanks in advance
**Edit 1**: I'm using SQL Server
**Edit 2**: Here's an actual picture:

[image]

It should show "Contact Me" below About (as the `Parent` field indicates)
**NOTE:** In this sample, `Order` is not a foreign key. It's just an `int` which is used for sorting.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select PageName from Pages 
order by isnull(Parent,0),ISNULL(Predecessor,0)
```

Comment: Actually, I feel stupid asking this question... Your solution obviously works. I spent hours thinking about using a group by clause... Must be the lack of sleep! Thanks dude :-)

Comment: @M2X: It happens to every body .. :) sometimes sitting on silly things for long time

Comment: Ok so it seems that I was rash! It's not working as I expected! I want to first sort by `Parent` and then sort parents by `Predecessor`

Comment: could you please give me a sample output?

Answer (score 1):

Something like below?

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM test t1 LEFT JOIN test t2 
ON t1.id=t2.parent
WHERE t1.parent IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.id,t2.id
```